# Data replaced by [object NodeList] when I try to print out into textarea field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form with some input fields and then take those input fields and place them into a textarea field.

Here is my JS script:

```
    function sayDetails() {

    var name = document.getElementsByName("userName"),
    address = document.getElementsByName("userAddress"),
    city = document.getElementsByName("userCity"),
    email = document.getElementsByName("userEmail"),
    final_txt = "Name: " + name + "Address: " + address + "City: " + city + "Email: " + email;

    document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = final_txt;

    return false;
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<div class="form">
<form name="userDetails">

Name:    <input type="text" name="userName" id="uName" required><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="userAddress" id="uAddress"><br>
City:    <input type="text" name="userCity" id="uCity"><br>
Email:   <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="uEmail" required><br>
</form>
<br>
 <input type="submit" form="userDetails" value="Submit form" onclick="sayDetails();">
<input type="button" form="userDetails" id="resetBtn" value="Reset" />
<br>
<textarea style="width:600px;height:100px;" id="outputArea" disabled></textarea>
</div>
```

After running it however, in the textarea field it shows this:

```
Name: [object NodeList]<br/>Address: [object NodeList]<br/>City: [object NodeList]<br/>Email: [object NodeList]
```

And what I would want it to display is:

```
Name: name here
Address: address here
City: city here
Email: email here
```

Where did I go wrong, and how can I make my code more efficient? Also, a little help to show me how to make the form input field lined up would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** After a few correction here and there, and thanks to you guys I was able to do it correctly.

Here is the new and revised JS script that correctly displays the  details the way I want it.

```
    function sayDetails() {

        var name = document.getElementById("uName").value;
        var address = document.getElementById("uAddress").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("uCity").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("uEmail").value;
        var final_txt = "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Adress:" + address +  "\n" + "City: " + city +  "\n" + "email:" + email;

        document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = final_txt;


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (collections of nodes)

For getting first item you should use like this:

```
 var name = document.getElementsByName("userName")[0],
    address = document.getElementsByName("userAddress")[0],
    city = document.getElementsByName("userCity")[0],
    email = document.getElementsByName("userEmail")[0]
```

And then for each `Node` you can get the value, for example:

```
name.value
```

Comment: I see, this concept is new to me and gives me something to read up on, thanks!

Comment: Extra question, can I know how to add line breaks in between the elements name, address, city and email please?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you print `node list` objects as a string then its `primitive` value will be printed. No wonder in that. Try to write your code like below,

```
final_txt = "Name: " + name[0].value + "Address: " + address[0].value + "City: " + city[0].value + "Email: " + email[0].value;
```

And I saw there are ids assigned with input elements, better use that instead of name for selecting the elements like,

```
var name = document.getElementById("uName").value;
```

Comment: Quick question, how do I add the linebreaks in between the name, address, city and email? My code displays the <br/> instead of giving me a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById` remember is unique

```
function sayDetails() {

var name = document.getElementById("uName").value,
address = document.getElementById("uAddress").value,
city = document.getElementById("uCity").value,
email = document.getElementById("uEmail").value,
final_txt = "Name: " + name + "Address: " + address + "City: " + city + "Email: " + email;

document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = final_txt;

return false;
```

}